# Application output is blank in Monodevelop

Tags: debugging, monodevelop

My debugging info has vanished in monodevelop.

debug is selected.

"emit debugging information" is on.

Application output is empty :(

I've tried console.writeline, debug.writeline and trace.writeline.

It's making debugging really difficult.

Comment: can you give a few more details of your setup, such as what platform you are running MonoDevelop on, and which version? CHEERS

Comment: Mac OS X Lion, monodevelop 3.05.

Comment: If i start a new project, it starts working again. The project that doesn't work though is very big and I don't want to start messing with it. I just need to turn the application output back on.

Comment: Ok, you could check the menu item Project > "solutionName" Options > Edit > Run > General > Configuration (select "Debug"). Make sure that the checkbox "Run on external console", and "Pause console output". Just a thought. If that isn't it, check again. But, you should at least be able to run your program from your terminal by using "mono 'program_name' ". Of course you have to navigate your terminal there. You can do that by typing "cd " in the terminal and dragging the "Debug" folder for your project into the terminal. (I hope I'm not telling you stuff you already know!) (if so, sorry)

Comment: Yep, tried all those, every combination. I don't really want to start having to run it from the console all the time. I didn't mention before but when I start the app I get a dialog box in monodevelop "Waiting for debugger" the only option on it is cancel and it never gets anywhere.

Comment: Can you step back to a time when this large software project did something more helpful for you? Do you have an earlier branch you can check out and play with? Or did this problem begin to manifest itself after a change / upgrade in MonoDevelop or OS? Sorry, I didn't originally understand it was a GUI application. I think if you can step back to an earlier version / or an earlier time, maybe looking at what changed will help sort out the problem?

Comment: I don't know if it's monodevelop because I have other projects that work fine. This big application works fine, it's just a bitch to debug now. I might have to create a new project, copy everything over and see if I can get that up and running, what a pain.

Comment: Ok, I understand that MD works fine for other projects, but I'm trying to ask debugging info to help you get going on your big project going. So if I understand you correctly, it is only when you try to debug it that you have a problem with your big project? And do you have some older branch to work from so you can step back to a time when debugging worked?

Comment: This started working this week after the a monodevelop update.

Answer (score 0):

A little late on the ball. But maybe it can help someone else.

In order to get your output to the application output window you will need to uncheck "Run on external console" under right click of your startup project > Options > Run > General > Configurations > "Configuration name".